# Show Time $T(n) = Θ(n^3)$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I have to show that : $$T(n) = Θ({n^3})$$

---

We have this recursive function :

$$T(n) = 8T(n/2) + n^2, n>=2$$

also we know that $$T(1) = 1$$

And it says that there is a "replacement method" to do that.

---

### EDIT

---

If I say $$n = 2^k, k≥1$$

then T(n) will become...
$$T(2^k) = 8T(2^k/2) + (2^k)^2$$

$$T(2^k+1) = 8T(2^(k+1) + (2^k+1)^2$$

and I can't get to Θ(n^3)

Comment: *Hint:* Consider the ["Master theorem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%27s_Theorem).

Comment: Alternatively, change the variable to $m$ where $n=2^m$. Then you can write down $T(2^m)$ as an explicit sum of different powers of $2$ and show that it's $\Theta(2^{3m})$.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I am doing but I can't find the way to Θ(2^3m).

Comment: Since this seems to be homework, I should probably warn you that the part the accepted answer deals with (powers of 2) might not get you a full mark since it is not sufficient to solve the question (full sequence).

Comment: @Did Thanks for your interest. Yes it was homework but I didn't send it. I just wanted to understand a bit, how to solve this so I will be ready for the exams :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to use cancellation.

$$
T(2^k) = 2^3\,T(2^{k-1}) + 2^{2(k)}\quad.
$$
You want to eliminate the $2^3\,T(2^{k-1})$ so you find an expression for it:

$$
T(2^{k-1}) = 2^3\,T(2^{k-2}) + 2^{2(k-1)} \implies
2^3\,T(2^{k-1}) = 2^{6}\,T(2^{k-2}) + 2^{2k+1} \quad.
$$
Continuing in this manner, we have

$$\begin{align}
T(2^k) &= 2^3\,T(2^{k-1}) + 2^{2k} \\
2^3\,T(2^{k-1}) &= 2^{6}\,T(2^{k-2}) + 2^{2k+1} \\
2^6\,T(2^{k-2}) &= 2^{9}\,T(2^{k-3}) + 2^{2k+2} \\
&\cdots \\
2^{3(k-1)}\,T(2^{k-(k-1)}) &= 2^{3k}\,T(2^{k-k}) + 2^{2k+(k-1)} \\
\end{align}
$$
Sum up the columns and terms on the left hand side cancel almost all terms on the right hand side. And you arrive at

$$\begin{align}
T(2^k) &= 2^{3k}T(2^0) + 2^{2k}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^i \\
&= 2^{3k}T(1) + 2^{2k}(2^k-1) \\
&= 2n^3 - n^2 \quad=\quad \Theta(n^3)\quad.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(k)=T(2^k)/8^k$. Then $S(k)=S(k-1)+1/4^k$ for $k\geqslant1$ and $S(0)=1$ hence, for every $k\geqslant0$,
$$1\leqslant S(k)\leqslant1+1/4+1/4^2+\cdots\leqslant2.
$$
Thus, for every $k\geqslant0$, $(2^k)^3\leqslant T(2^k)\leqslant2\cdot(2^k)^3$.

For every $n\geqslant1$ there exists $k\geqslant0$ such that $2^k\leqslant n\leqslant 2^{k+1}$ hence, **if the sequence $T$ is nondecreasing** then 
$$T(n)\leqslant T(2^{k+1})\leqslant16\cdot(2^k)^3\leqslant16\cdot n^3,
$$ and 
$$T(n)\geqslant T(2^{k})\geqslant(2^k)^3\geqslant\frac18\cdot n^3.
$$
In particular, 
$$T(n)=\Theta(n^3).$$

Comment: Can you solve it with the way Henning said? With n = 2^m.

Comment: This is exactly what I did.